# What will be the memory layout diagram for following statement in lisp?

Tags: lisp

I don't know how to draw memory layout for this and I'm new to lisp. Please help me out.

```lisp
(car (cdr ( cdr '(12  (*3 4)  (+ 3 4)  (/4 2)  23))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are talking about Common Lisp, and not other kind of lisp, you can use `sdraw` (after loading it from this page: https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~dst/Lisp/sdraw/sdraw.genericv) to show the memory layout of your form (in lisp there are not statements, but forms). Note that you have to format correctly the form, by inserting spaces when appropriate (for instance, between the operator and its first argument, like `(* 3 4)` and not `(*3 4)` that are two completely different forms).

So, for instance (this is printed only to a certain level of the tree, see the `etc.` part):

```
CL-USER> (sdraw '(car (cdr ( cdr '(12 (* 3 4) (+ 3 4) (/ 4 2) 23)))))

[*|*]--->[*|*]--->NIL
 |        |
 v        v
CAR      [*|*]--->[*|*]--->NIL
          |        |
          v        v
         CDR      [*|*]--->[*|*]--->NIL
                   |        |
                   v        v
                  CDR      [*|*]--->[*|*]--->NIL
                            |        |
                            v        v
                           QUOTE    [*|*]--->[*|*]--->etc.
                                     |        |
                                     v        v
                                     12      [*|*]--->[*|*]--->[*|*]--->NIL
                                              |        |        |
                                              v        v        v
                                              *        3        4
```

Each box represents a cons cell, with two fields pointing to the car and the cdr of the cell.

Comment: That link appears broken... Perhaps you meant https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~dst/Lisp/sdraw/sdraw.generic ?

Comment: Yes, that is the link.